# Find the base of the range space of this matrix:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the base of the range space of this matrix:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        4 & 1 & 1 \\
        3 & 2 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I am really not sure how to proceed and could not determine what is a range space of a matrix. What is the range space of a matrix?

Comment: The range of a matrix $A$ is the column space (usually, notated as $C(A)$). You may check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces).

Comment: So its the set of linear independent vectors in the matrix?

Comment: Actually, the column space is  the linear subspace spanned by the column vectors. Now, in order to find a basis for the column space, you need to define a set of linearly independent column vectors.

Comment: Are you using determinants yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range space is also called the column space.  The column space in this case is $$\operatorname{span}\left((4,3,1)^T,(1,2,1)^T,(1,0,0)^T\right)$$

But we don't know if those three vectors are linearly independent or not, yet. So to find a basis we just do column reduction (we'd use row reduction if we wanted a basis for the *row* space) until we get it into reduced column echelon form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
        4 & 1 & 1 \\
        3 & 2 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 4 \\
        0 & 2 & 3 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} \sim \cdots \sim \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

So $$\left\{(1,0,0)^T,(0,1,0)^T,(0,0,1)^T\right\}$$ is a basis for the column space in this case.

Comment: Would you not use the original columns?

Comment: @budder You could if you want.  Column reduction preserves the column space.  That means you can use any set of column vectors from any of the steps in your column reduction.  The standard basis vectors obtained at the end are a little more convenient than the original columns, though.

Comment: I don't see how you end up with $I$ :(. I imagine after the first step you would subtract col 3 from col 2, ending up with $\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -3 & 4 \\
        0 & -1 & 3 \\
        0 &  0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$. What am I missing ?